# Multiple Login in same django project

Tags: django

I have a django project with 3 apps: CORE, FRONT-A and FRONT-B. So, each APP should have your own login page, something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/front-a/login
http://localhost:8080/front-b/login
```

**CORE** app have Django Admin and Models, that should be used by FRONT-A and FRONT-B app, like a shared "jar" in java.

But some login properties i have to configure in settings.xml, like this:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'FRONT-A OR FRONT-B ?'
```

So, i have some doubts:

1. In my case is better create one project for FRONT-A and another for FRONT-B, because i need different login pages ?
2. **If answer for (1) is NO**, how can i create a login page for each APP, and grant session for each APP ?
3. **If answer for (1) is YES**, can i use CORE App as shared library to my another projects ? I want to avoid "duplicate code".
4. How can i know if i need APP onyl or create another whole PROJECT ?

Comment: What about decorator `@login_required(login_url="your/login/url")` while writing your views and provide login_url accordingly?

Comment: So, is not wrong have multiple login pages in same project?

Comment: Okay so let me have a little clarity here. You are interested in having multiple login pages AND NOT multiple authentication backends, right?

Comment: Exactly but user front-a can't login in front-b and vice versa

Comment: I guess what u wish to do can be done using groups and permissions.

Comment: But I have the problem in settings.py where I need configure login page, but I have multiples

Comment: You dont have to configure login url in settings.py if you are going to use `@login_required` with `login_url` argument.

Comment: Do you have any example how to multiple login page ?